# Get keys and values of JSONField

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to pass keys and values of my list of dicts from `JSONField` to `XHR` as `JSON`.

The content of `JSONField` looks like:

```
[{'q1':'12'},{'q2':'22'},{'q3':'11'}]
```

And I want to pass them as same as list above.

models.py:

```
class User1(models.Model):
    history = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User1
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User1
    template_name = None
    ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
            if request.headers.get('Get-History') == 'History':
                form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
                self.object = self.get_object()    
                
                data = {
                    'history': str(form.fields['history'])
                }

                return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Result:

```
{"history": "<django.forms.fields.JSONField object at 0x109d03080>"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to substitute

```
return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

with:

```
return JsonResponse(data['history'])
```

This happens because you are calling `data`, which is a JSON object.

Actually this line

```
{"history": "<django.forms.fields.JSONField object at 0x109d03080>"}
```

means: a dictionary having one field, where the key is history and its value is a JSON object coming from django forms.

What you actually want is not the entire dictionary, but the value of one of its keys.